# Answers on Careers.SE look different

Tags: bug, jobs, mathjax

My answers are being misrepresented on careers.stackoverflow.com...

Here's how they look on careers:

[image: Careers applying scrummy layout]

Here's how they're supposed to look:

[image: Code Review answer lookin' good]

Weird font change for quoted text, and no mathjax support ruins my answer.

I don't want to edit my answer just so my resume looks good. Is there a way for me to make my answers look properly on my profile?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for reporting this. There is nothing you can do at the moment to alter the formatting of your answers on your profile. We've triaged this to investigate the issue further and will update this answer when we have more information.

**Update:** We're going to add this to our product backlog, but can't provide an expected rollout date. Thanks again.